# Changes not staged after git add

Tags: git

Why would I get items in the `Changes not staged for commit` after I run `git add .`?

```
> git add .
> git st 

# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#   (commit or discard the untracked or modified content in submodules)
#
#       modified:   bin/ls-- (modified content, untracked content)
#
```

This is on `Red Hat 4.1.2-50` with `git 1.7.10.`

Comment: Which version are you using? In which operating system do you work?

Comment: It is very strange. It worked for me. With `git add bin`, does it work?

Comment: Thanks @WilliamSeitiMizuta. No - I just tried `git add bin` and it still reports the entry in `changes not staged for commit`

Comment: My guess is that `git add .` did add the file, but it was then modified again somehow before your `git st` (which I assume is an alias for `git status <some flags>` or something). Although when I test that scenario, I get the file listed in two separate sections rather than the `(modified content, untracked content)` indicator you show - not sure if an older version of `git` might have reported it that way or something...

Comment: Thanks @twalberg - I have tried staging and committing several times now (being explicit with `bin` or not), and I still get the same item "Changes not staged for commit". Very odd.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears, that `bin/ls` is a [submodule](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules).

When you `cd` into this directory and run `git status` you should see what content is modified and untracked, and you will be able to commit that into the sumbodule's base repository.

After that, when there will be a new commit at the HEAD of submodule's repository you can `git add` this change in your main repository and commit there.

Comment: The reason for this kind of behaviour is that git keeps in the main repository only pointers to the specific commits in submodules and only when the HEAD of submodule is moved there will be any commitable change in the main repository.

Comment: Wow, OK, I think you are right, since I see a .git folder inside `/bin/ls--`. The odd thing is that I am pretty sure I never added it as a submodule of the main repository (i.e. with `git submodule add`). Hmmm.

Comment: Look for `.gitmodules` file in the main repository.

Comment: Hmm. There is no `.gitmodules` in the main repository, but I bet you are still right.

Answer (score 14):

Try `git add -A` and then check the status to commit